# Integration by part for solving $\int \tan^{-1}\sqrt{x}\; dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to solve the intgral is given by
$$\int_{0}^{1}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x} \;dx$$
I set $dx=dv$ and $\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x}=u$ but I do not recieve good result. please give me hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t=\sqrt{x}$, so $x=t^2$ and $dx=2tdt$ to get $\displaystyle\int_0^1\tan^{-1}t\cdot 2tdt=2\int_0^1t\tan^{-1}tdt$.

Now let $\displaystyle u=\tan^{-1}t, du=\frac{1}{t^2+1}dt\;$ and $\;dv=tdt, v=\frac{1}{2}(t^2+1)$ to get

$\displaystyle2\left[\frac{1}{2}(t^2+1)\tan^{-1}t-\frac{1}{2}t\right]_0^1=\left[(t^2+1)\tan^{-1}t-t\right]_0^1$

Comment: so thanks user84413

Answer (score 3):

if $f$ be differentiable , injective and increasing on $[a,b]$ such that $f(a)=\alpha$ and $f(b)=\beta$ ,then
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx+\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}f^{-1}(x)dx=b\,\beta-a\,\alpha$$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x} dx+\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan^2 x dx=\frac{\pi}{4}$$
then
$$\int_{0}^{1}\tan^{-1}\sqrt{x} dx=\frac{\pi}{2}-1$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Do integration by parts. $$\begin{align*}\int \arctan\sqrt{x}\,{\rm d}x &=  x\arctan\sqrt{x} - \int x \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{1+(\sqrt{x}^2)}\,{\rm d}x \\ &= x\arctan\sqrt{x} - \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x}\,{\rm d}x\end{align*}$$That last integral you can solve by making $u=1+x$.